# CORBA via IIOP: Calling methods accepting enums

Tags: c#, .net, corba, iiop

I am trying to access the interface `LicenseServerFactory` described in the follwing IDL:

```
typedef sequence<octet> usBuffer;

enum LicenseClientUTFType {LIC_UTF16 , LIC_UTF32};

exception NotAuthenticated {};
exception UserNotConnected {};

interface LicenseServer
{
    long SBOConnect (in usBuffer User, in usBuffer Company, in usBuffer PCName, out usBuffer SessionE, in long lDate, in usBuffer sInstallNo) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long AddOnGetLicense (in usBuffer Identifier, in usBuffer User, in usBuffer Company, in usBuffer PCName, out long plSessionID, out usBuffer SessionE, in long lDate, in usBuffer sInstallNo) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long PollSession (in usBuffer User, in usBuffer SIDs, out usBuffer RetE) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long SessionsInfo (in usBuffer User, in usBuffer SessionsInfo, out usBuffer SessionsInfoE, in long lDate) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long SessionVerify (in usBuffer User, in long lSessionID, out usBuffer pSessionIdE) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long CloseSession (in usBuffer User, in long lSessionId) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long LockServer (in usBuffer User, in long lSessionID) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long UnLockServer (in usBuffer User, in long lSessionID) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetUserLicenseInfo (in usBuffer User, out usBuffer pModules, out boolean pbIsConnected) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetAllModulesStatus (out usBuffer pModulesInfo) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long LoadLicenseFile (in usBuffer NewLicenseFile) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetHardwareKey (out usBuffer pHK) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long CreateIdentifier (in usBuffer Addon, out usBuffer pIdentifier, in usBuffer sInstallNo) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetAllUsersLicenseInfo(out usBuffer pUsersLicInfo) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long SetAllUsersLicenseInfo(in usBuffer User, in usBuffer UsersLicInfo, out usBuffer pConnectedUser) raises(NotAuthenticated,UserNotConnected);
    long IsDevExist (in usBuffer sInstallNo);
    long GetInstallationNumberList(out usBuffer pInstNum);
    long GetSystemNumber (out usBuffer pSysNum, in usBuffer sInstallNo);
    long GetFutureExpired(in long lFutureDate, out usBuffer pModules, in usBuffer sInstallNo);
    long GetUserSessionsInfo(in usBuffer UserName,out usBuffer pRsltSessionsInfo);
    long GetBIGSLicense (in usBuffer User, in usBuffer Company, in usBuffer PCName, in long lNum, out usBuffer pSessionsE, in long lDate, in usBuffer sInstallNo) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    boolean IsLicenseFileExist();
    long GetVersion(out usBuffer sVersion);
    long ClearUserLicenses (in usBuffer User) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long UpdateUserLicenses (in usBuffer User, out usBuffer ModulesE, in long lDate, in long lSessionID, in usBuffer sCmpLocalization, in usBuffer sCmpVersion) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long RequestNamedLicenses (in usBuffer User, out usBuffer ModulesE, in long lDate, in long lSessionID, in usBuffer sCmpLocalization, in usBuffer sCmpVersion) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long IsLicenseConcurrent () raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetLicenseFileGenInfo(in usBuffer sInstallNo, out usBuffer sLicGenInfo);
    //long DeleteLicenseFile (in usBuffer sInstallNo) raises(NotAuthenticated);

    long HandShake(in long algorithm, in usBuffer publicKey, out usBuffer sessionKey) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetCompanyDBCredentials(in long dbType, in usBuffer server, in usBuffer company, in usBuffer user, in usBuffer password, out usBuffer dbUser, out usBuffer dbPassword, out boolean useTrusted) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetDBCredentials(in long dbType, in usBuffer server, in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password, out usBuffer dbUser, out usBuffer dbPassword, out boolean useTrusted) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetCompanyReadOnlyDBCredentials(in long dbType, in usBuffer server, in usBuffer company, in usBuffer user, in usBuffer password, out usBuffer dbUser, out usBuffer dbPassword) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetReadOnlyDBCredentials(in long dbType, in usBuffer server, in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password, out usBuffer dbUser, out usBuffer dbPassword) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetListOfCompanies(in long dbType, in usBuffer server, in boolean refresh, out usBuffer listOfCompanies);
    long GetCompanyEncryptionConfig(in long dbType, in usBuffer server, in usBuffer company, in usBuffer user, in usBuffer password, out long algorithm, out usBuffer keyId, out usBuffer key) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetEncryptionConfig(in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password, out long algorithm,  out usBuffer keyId, out usBuffer key) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long SetDBCredentials(in long dbType, in usBuffer server, in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password, in usBuffer dbUser, in usBuffer dbPassword, in boolean useTrusted) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long RemoveDBCredentials(in long dbType, in usBuffer server, in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetServerVersion(in long dbType, in usBuffer server, out usBuffer version, in usBuffer commonDBName);
    long SetReadOnlyDBCredentials(in long dbType, in usBuffer server, in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password, in usBuffer dbUser, in usBuffer dbPassword) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long SetEncryptionAlghorithm(in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password, in long algorithm) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GenerateEncryptionKey(in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetServicesUserCredentials(in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password, out usBuffer servicesUser, out usBuffer servicesPassword) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long ExportSecuritySettings(in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password, out usBuffer xmlSettings) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long ImportSecuritySettings(in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password, in usBuffer xmlSettings) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetListOfConfiguredServers(out usBuffer listOfServers);
    long GetSiteUserName(out usBuffer siteUser);
    long AuthenticateSiteUser(in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password, out boolean result) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long AuthenticateServicesUser(in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password, out boolean result) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long ChangeSiteUserPassword(in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer oldPassword, in usBuffer password) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long ChangeSiteUserPasswordByDB(in long dbType, in usBuffer server, in usBuffer dbUser, in usBuffer dbPassword, in usBuffer password) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetCompanyStaticKey(in long dbType, in usBuffer server, in usBuffer company, in usBuffer user, in usBuffer password, out usBuffer key) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetStaticKey(in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password, out usBuffer key) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetEncryptionAlgorithm(out long algorithm);
    long IsNTTrusted(in long dbType, in usBuffer server, out boolean isNTTrusted);
    long IsDKeyUsed(out boolean result);
    long ExportDKeys(in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password, out usBuffer xmlDKeys) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long ImportDKeys(in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password, in usBuffer xmlDKeys) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GenerateDKey(in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password, out usBuffer xmlDKeys) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long EnableDKey(in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password, out usBuffer xmlDKeys) raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetCompanyKeyAndKeyState(in long dbType, in usBuffer server, in usBuffer company, in usBuffer user, in usBuffer password, in usBuffer compKeyId, out long keyState, out usBuffer compKey)raises(NotAuthenticated);
    long GetKeyAndKeyState(in usBuffer siteUser, in usBuffer password, in usBuffer compKeyId, out long keyState, out usBuffer compKey)raises(NotAuthenticated);

};

interface LicenseServerFactory
{
  LicenseServer GetLicenseServer(in LicenseClientUTFType ClientUTFType);
};
```

using the following C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;

using omg.org.CosNaming;
using Ch.Elca.Iiop;
using Ch.Elca.Iiop.Services;
using Ch.Elca.Iiop.Idl;

[Ch.Elca.Iiop.Idl.RepositoryID("IDL:LicenseServer:1.0")]
public interface IGtLicenseServer
{   Int32 AuthenticateSiteUser    ([IdlSequence(0)] byte[] siteUser, [IdlSequence(0)] byte[] password, out bool result);
    Int32 AuthenticateServicesUser([IdlSequence(0)] byte[] siteUser, [IdlSequence(0)] byte[] password, out bool result);
}

[IdlEnumAttribute]
public enum LicenseClientUTFType {LIC_UTF16 , LIC_UTF32};

[Ch.Elca.Iiop.Idl.RepositoryID("IDL:LicenseServerFactory:1.0")]
public interface LicenseServerFactory
{
    IGtLicenseServer GetLicenseServer(LicenseClientUTFType ClientUTFType);
};
// [...]
// This is a class's constructor:
public LicenseServer(string server, int port)
{   NameComponent[] names = null;
    CorbaInit init = CorbaInit.GetInit();
    IiopClientChannel channel = new IiopClientChannel();
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
    NamingContext context = init.GetNameService(server, port);
    Binding[] binding;
    BindingIterator bi;
    context.list(4, out binding, out bi);   
    names = new NameComponent[] { new NameComponent("B1LicenseServer2008Factory") };
    LicenseServerFactory lf = ( LicenseServerFactory )context.resolve( names );
    IGtLicenseServer ls = lf.GetLicenseServer(LicenseClientUTFType.LIC_UTF32);
}
```

and get the following error: "CORBA system exception : omg.org.CORBA.BAD_PARAM, completed: Completed_MayBe minor: 10030" during the call to `lf.GetLicenseServer()`. Do you have any suggestions as to what may be causing it?